# Partitioning a set of rectangles into disjoint subsets each of which consists of disjoint rectangles

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose we have a list $R$ of axis-aligned rectangles in the plane. There is the well-known problem of determining the maximum subset of $R$ which consists of disjoint rectangles; this problem is known to be NP-hard. There are reasonably efficient algorithms, however, for finding approximations to the maximal independent subset; e.g., see this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772198000285).

I have a twist on this problem. I don't need the maximal independent subset or even a single approximation to it. Rather, I need a *list* of subsets $R_1,R_2,\dots,R_k$, each of which consists of disjoint rectangles, such that $R_1\cup R_2\cup\dots\cup R_k = R$. It is not necessary that the sets $R_1,\dots,R_k$ themselves be disjoint, though in an ideal solution they would be. I want to find such a list as quickly as possible, with the additional optimization constraint that each individual list should be large (so as to rule out the trivial solution where each list consists of a single rectangle).

If you're curious about the motivation of this problem, it arises in cartography when one wishes to dynamically label a map: each set of labelings corresponds to a set $R_i$ above, and the interactive map cycles through the label sets $R_i$ over time so that all labels are guaranteed to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another formulation of your problem: you have a (not neccessarily planar) graph (its vertices are your rectangles and two vertices are connected by an edge if these rectangles overlap) and are looking for a [coloring of its vertices](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/vertex-coloring.shtml) (each color being one of your subsets $R_i$) using a low but not neccessarily minimal number of colors.

There exist various [algorithms for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms), with different tradeoffs between speed and quality of the result. There is also [plenty of papers](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=graph%20coloring%20algorithm) written on this subject. [*The Algorithm Design Manual*](http://www.algorist.com/) by Skiena suggests http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Coloring/ and http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/COLOR/color.html as useful resources, and also gives help in choosing an algorithm as well as an overview of existing implementations. Among these implementations are [GraphCol](http://code.google.com/p/graphcol/) and [GOBLIN](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/). It also has plenty of suggestions for further reading.